# Is there anywhere a reference of all OpenID providers that support SREG or AX?

Tags: reference, openid, sreg

It could be a useful resource - website-reference, listing all the OpenID providers along with the features they support - SREG and/or AX, PAPE policies, etc.

Are there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still lacks a lot of (major) providers, but [this could be a good starting point](http://willnorris.com/openid-support).

I'm surprised because this table gives the impression that sreg is far more developed than ax, although, from my own experience, both Yahoo! and Google use the later.